# How do you create a link out of circular text with JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I am using jQuery and [CircleType.js](https://circletype.labwire.ca/) to have text show in a circular pattern.  My question is how can I make the text in the circle a hyperlink?  The circletype.js automatically removes any `a` elements that are used, and since this method puts a span tag around each letter, I am not sure how you could use circletype.js with a link.

Is there another way to to wrap text in a circular shape with links without using circletype.js?  I am still a newb at JavaScript, so if there is a way to create the links with JS, then any help getting on to the right path to write the script for this would be great.  My code below (minus the css):

```
<body>
<div id="img-container">
    <p id="link-circle">
        LINK &diams; LINK &diams; LINK &diams; LINK &diams; LINK &diams;&nbsp;
    </p>
    <a href="#">
        <div id="switch">
            <form action="">
                <input type="radio" id="left-radio" name="Column Select" value="left"/>
                <input type="radio" id="right-radio" name="Column Select" value="right"/>
            </form>
            <span id="dbl-chevron">&raquo;</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#link-circle').circleType();
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Here is an example:

[image: Example]

Maybe even a way to overlay a div layer over the text to create links would work.  But I am not sure which way to go with this.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you want the full circle to be a link? That would be easy by wrapping it with an `<a>` tag. Otherwise, replace the content of each span with a letter wrapper with an `<a>` after "circlifying" it. But.. That would probably be overkill.

Comment: Or you can wrap the whole thing with <a>, which is perfectly valid in HTML5

Comment: with js you can create a click event and redirect to another page

Comment: Hm... interesting HTML output - every letter is separated and wrapped in span tag,  with separated classes (from char1 to charx)...it would be pretty hard...

Comment: Maybe you could rather try with this approach: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircularNavigation/index2.html

Comment: @nevermind - That looks promising for the circle navigation.  I will look into that.  Way cleaner than what I am doing probably.

Comment: @blex - I am trying to make each "Link" text be a link, not the whole circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at [the plugin's code](https://github.com/peterhry/CircleType/blob/master/js/circletype.js) and playing with it, I discovered that it was the required [LetteringJS](http://letteringjs.com/) plugin that was removing any tags.

They call it on line 33: `$(elem).lettering();`

Then I came up with an idea.

## What can we do?

- We can save the HTML of our element before it gets split up by [LetteringJS](http://letteringjs.com/).
- Then, let it do its work.
- After that, we can put our tags back around each letter that was contained in one.

## Partial solution

#### Why "partial"?

My solution will only work on:

1. **non self-closing tags:** no `<img/>`, `<input/>`, etc. but I don't think that's likely to happen.
2. **non nested tags:** no `<b><a></a></b>`, but you can fake that with classes - see demo below.

#### How does it work?

We need to change [CircleType](http://circletype.labwire.ca/)'s source code so that it does what we want. I've commented my code, but if you don't understand something, or find a mistake or an improvement to make, don't hesitate to tell me!

```
// trim spaces at the beginning and at the end
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

// grab the HTML string
var temp = elem.innerHTML;

// replace any space that is not part of a tag with a non-breakable space (&nbsp;)
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(/<[^<>]+>|\s/g, function(s) {
                     return s[0] == '<' ? s : '&nbsp;';
                 });

// wrap each character in a span
$(elem).lettering();


var inTag = false, // are we between tags? (<i>here</i>)
    isTag = false, // are we inside a tag? (<here></here>)
    tagNum = -1,   // how many opening tags have we met so far? (minus 1)
    pos = 0,       // character position (excluding tags)
    dom = document.createElement('div'); // temporary dom

dom.innerHTML = temp; // clone our element in the temporary dom

var tags = dom.children; // children of the element
// for each of them, empty their content
for(var i=0, l=tags.length; i<l; i++){
    tags[i].innerHTML = '';
}

// for each character in our HTML string
for(var i=0, l= temp.length; i<l; i++){
    var c = temp[i];
    // if it's a '<'
    if(c == '<'){
        // and if it's an opening tag
        if(!inTag){
            // increment the number of tags met
            tagNum++;
            // we're in a tag!
            inTag = true;
        }
        else{
            // otherwise we're in a closing tag
            inTag = false;
        }
        // we're on a tag (<here>)
        isTag = true;
    }
    // if it's a '>'
    else if(c == '>'){
        // we're not <here> anymore
        isTag = false;
    }
    // if we're not <here>
    else if(!isTag){
        // if we're <b>here</b>
        if(inTag){
            // replace the span's content with our tag
            elem.children[pos].innerHTML = tags[tagNum].outerHTML;
            // put the letter back in
            elem.children[pos].children[0].innerHTML = c;
        }
        // move forward in the spans
        pos++;
    }
}
```

## Resources

- #### JS Fiddle Demo
- #### Updated plugin source

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways of doing this with jQuery.

One is to do a `wrapInner()` on the div after the circle has been created.

The other is to do an `click()` event which will run a javascript redirect.

I would personally side with the `wrapInner()` method.

### Wrap

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var link = $('#link-circle').find('a').attr('href');
        $('#link-circle').circleType().wrapInner('<a href="'+link+'"></a>');
    });
</script>
```

### Redirect

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#link-circle').circleType();
        $('#link-circle').click(function() {
            window.location.href = "your link here";
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried wrapping each linkwith `<a>` tags like:

```
<p id="link-circle">
    <a href="#">LINK</a> &diams; 
    <a href="#">LINK</a> &diams; 
    <a href="#">LINK</a> &diams; 
    <a href="#">LINK</a> &diams; 
    <a href="#">LINK</a> &diams;
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, this I tried.  This is how I know that circletype.js removes the a element from the what it processes.